# Destructure a function parameter subproperty

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've got a `Function` that I want to be able to call in 2 ways - and it should behave the same.

Is there any ES6 syntax that will allow me to call the function `doBar` below using *both* ways with the same result?

Consider a function like this:

```
const doBar = ({ foo = 'bar' }) => {
  console.log(foo) // should log 'baz'
}
```

I'm using a framework that binds events like so:

```
<x-component on-some-event="doBar"></x-component>
```

which will essentially cause an invocation like so:

```
// where e = { detail: { foo: 'baz' } }
doBar(e)
```

.. but I'd like to be able to both call my `Function` *explicitly as well*, albeit with a proper call signature like so:

```
doBar({ foo: 'baz' })
```

Comment: I guess you're looking for `const { foo } = e.detail || e`

Comment: @Bergi I would rather keep it in the function arguments, Ori Drori's answer below has me covered

Comment: It does howerver switch on the existence of the `foo` property, not the existence of the `detail` property - and will get less impressive when you want to destructure multiple properties.

Comment: @Bergi I'm guessing you're saying it's not very scalable when more arguments/props come into play - Care to write up an answer explaining this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). If `foo` is not found, it will use the value of `detail.foo`.

```js
const doBar = ({ detail = {}, foo = detail.foo }) => {
  console.log(foo) // should log 'baz'
}

doBar({ foo: 'baz' })


doBar({
  detail: {
    foo: 'baz'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this properly in the parameter declaration. Just put your destructuring assignment in the function body:

```
function doBar(e) {
  const { foo = "bar", qux } = e.detail || e;
  consoel.log(foo, qux);
}
```

> I'd like to be able to both call my function explicitly as well

I would recommend to not do that. A function should have one signature only and not be overloaded to different types of arguments. Just be explicit about when to use what:

```
function doBar({ foo = "bar", qux }) {
  console.log(foo);
}
function withDetail(fn) {
  return e => fn(e.detail)
}

<x-component on-some-event="withDetail(doBar)"></x-component>

doBar({ foo: 'baz' })
```

Comment: I've accepted the answer above but went with this one. I agree that it's bad design to have a function with 2 different call signatures.

Answer (score 0):

No. Not unless you consider this to be an adequate alternative:

```
const thing = {
  detail: {
    foo: 'baz'
  }
};

doBar(thing.detail);
```